# Cocoa, toll-free bridging and ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, stream, inputstream, tcpclient

I want to make a simples cliente of TCP. But I'm getting one error. When I make  `inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;` and `outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;` it suggests me to introduce the prefix __bridge or _*bridge*_transfer.

First, what is it? Second, I tried both and still can't send messages. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server.) and I've the send messages and stream too. I installed Wireshark and the send message is been called, but it's not sending any packet to the ip.

I've just posted here the initNetworkCommunication because is where I get the "bridge" error.

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"54.xxx.xxx.xxx", 1333, &readStream, &writeStream);

    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

}
```

The server is fine, because i've tried the sample code and I get a response.

Can you help me?

Comment: 1. These keywords are silly ARC-related stuff; you'd better turn off ARC for this project. 2. I've created an Objective-C TCP wrapper around the BSD sockets API which is really easy to use: http://github.com/H2CO3/TCPHelper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As H2CO3 mentioned, it's an ARC thing.

If you don't know what ARC is, [read this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). To summarise, it's a deterministic way of automating the memory management stuff (retain/release statements etc) that Objective-C programmers previously had to do manually. It's well worth using, and has few downsides. However, it does have a few gotcha's.

ARC doesn't work on Core Foundation objects. They're still subject to the old rules, where you have to do the memory management yourself. ARC only applies to Objective-C objects. However, some Core Foundation objects are actually toll-free bridged to their Cocoa equivalent. You're using toll-free bridging in your code sample, to create a `CFReadStreamRef` and then work with it as an `NSInputStream`.

So what do you do? Apple's docs say the following:

> If you cast between Objective-C and Core Foundation-style objects, you need to tell the compiler about the ownership semantics of the object using either a cast (defined in objc/runtime.h) or a Core Foundation-style macro (defined in NSObject.h):
>
> - `__bridge` transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.
> - `__bridge_retained` or `CFBridgingRetain` casts an Objective-C pointer to a Core Foundation pointer and also transfers ownership to you.
>     You are responsible for calling CFRelease or a related function to relinquish ownership of the object.
> - `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC.
>     ARC is responsible for relinquishing ownership of the object.

You're moving from Core Foundation to Objective-C, so ignore the second bullet point (that's for going in the other direction). The question is what do you want to happen — if after the transfer you want to hand that object to ARC, use it only from the Objective-C side, and have ARC deal with the memory management, use `__bridge_transfer`. That's probably what you want based on your code sample.

If you just use `__bridge`, or if you don't use ARC, you'll need to clear up the objects yourself, using either `CFRelease()` or by sending them a `release` message (the latter only works if you're not using ARC).

Comment: Thanks a lot Amy Worrall. Well, I've comed from simple Javascript and HTML Front End. I'm on IOS for about 2 months, and it's time to buy a book. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: No worries. ARC is definitely the future, so it's worth using — but we're in the transitional period where it's still new and lots of tutorials haven't been updated yet. Make sure when you get a book that you know whether it teaches you the old (manual retain/release) memory management rules or whether it uses ARC. It pays to at least be aware of the manual way of doing things, since it gives you a better understanding of just what ARC is automating.

Comment: I see. Well adding the __bridge_transfer won't work. My - (void) sendMessage:(NSString *)message {
    NSLog(@"message %@",message);
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
 [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]]; 
    NSLog(@"outputStream %@",outputStream);
} don't work :S I think there is a problem with the outputstream